# Power BI - How to fix "404 error" while publishing from Desktop to service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm getting "The remote server returned an error: 404 Not Found" error when trying to publish a specific report from Power BI Desktop to service on a specific workspace.

Providing more details:

- I'm using the latest version (Version: 2.68.5432.841 64-bit)
- The specific report I'm getting trouble to publish has Azure SQL database as the unique data source, using Mixed storage mode.
- I'm able to publish this file in "Marketing" workspace for example and I can access it online, but not able to publish the same file on "IT" workspace.
- I'm able to publish other files on "IT workspace"
- The user I'm logged in when trying to publish is "IT Workspace"s admin on both workspaces
- I've tried to publish via Get Data -> File on Power BI service, got an error too

I've searched through the forums and tried many of the solutions presented to this error in the past, 
I saw that over the course of the versions, Microsoft probably solved many of the issues that were causing it,
I tried all the possible turnarounds I saw in the community from old versions that had this kind of an error, like renaming the file, reconnecting, changing the type of connection, etc, etc and I'm still getting "The remote server returned an error: 404 Not Found" error.

Does anyone have any idea on what else I should check, please?